# The bottom border on the timeline page looks wrong if a title is multiline

Tags: feature-request, support, design, timeline

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9511/timeline

> [image]

```
<div class="subheader">
        <h1>
        </h1>
</div>
```

`.subheader` has style `border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;`.

The bottom border should be below the whole title (I guess, the point is to separate the whole title). But the `height` of this `div` is hardcoded `height: 40px;`.

Shouldn't it be like this? (the screenshot with `height: 80px;`).

> [image]